# Finding a sum of certain pth roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity, exponential-sum

Say $p\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $a$ is a primitive root$\pmod p$.  Can we find or estimate the value of $\sum_{i=1}^{(p-1)/n} \zeta^{a^i}$ and its conjugates?

Note that if $n$ is odd, this sum is real by Galois theory (it is fixed by a subgroup of the Galois group of order $n$).  Furthermore, its conjugates are of a similar form with $\zeta^{a^i}$ replaced with $\zeta^{t\cdot a^i}$.

As an example, if we take $7\equiv 1\pmod 3$, then we get $\zeta+\zeta^6$.  In general, can we expect this sum to be small?

Comment: Gauss started this topic in the D.A. Many examples at https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false  and a modern explanation at http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/cox_galois_Gaussian_periods.pdf

Comment: This is 9.2.C right?  Any results on the magnitude of such sums?

Comment: I see.  These are nth degree exponential sums where n=2 corresponds to the quadratic residue/reciprocity stuff.